Looking for a 21st century film about 12 lost and/or sacred scrolls
I remember this movie was about a guy going on vacation to a tropical place (maybe somewhere in Asia or South America) and he ended up getting tangled in this search for 12 sacred scrolls or something. The scrolls were like the answers to the universe, I guess, and a bunch of criminal goons for a big baddie were searching for them so they could them to take over or destroy the world or whatever. I don't know. I remember this one scene where the protagonist's soon-to-be love interest shows him how everything has an aura. She told him to look at a plant across from them and to really concentrate until he saw the plant's aura. There was this one part where he was close to getting caught by the baddies, so he meditated right there and he transferred to a different plain of existence. The plain where the auras were; so I guess some type of spirit realm.
I know it was called The Twelve "Somethings", like Sacred Scriptures or Scrolls or something. I really enjoyed it as a kid. Anybody know the movie I'm talking about? Please help if you can. Thank you!

How sure are you it was a movie as opposed to a television episode? What country was it released in? What year?

Well, it was after 2000 apparently, per the title

Sounds like The Celestine Prophecy from 2006, though it's 9 rather than 12.

Disillusioned and temporarily rudderless, John Woodson is about to experience a dramatic and profound metamorphosis. Through a mysterious set of coincidences, he finds himself on an adventure to Peru in search of ancient scrolls, known as the Celestine Prophecy. The prophecy and its nine key insights, predict a new awakening that redefines human life and provides a glimpse into a completely spiritual culture on earth. Resistant at first, skeptical and unsure, John finds that each step he takes, each person he encounters leads him to a new awakening.

Here's a scene where he's taught to see a plant's aura:




OMFG yes! Thank you so much!
